# Show that the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{a_{n}}{n}$ exists.

Tags: geometry, analysis

So $\left \{ a_{n} \right \}_{n\geq 1}$ is a sequence of real numbers and $C>0$ is a fixed constant. We assume that
$a_{n+m}\leq a_{n}+a_{m}+C, \forall n, m\geq 1$.

What is a good way to prove this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Look at [Fukket's lemma](http://planetmath.org/proofoffeketessubadditivelemma)

Comment: Note that $a_n$ is not subadditive, so you cannot use Fekete's lemma directly. You need to employ a simple trick first.

Comment: Are you sure "a sequence of real numbers"? E.g. $a_{n}=-n^2$ and $-(n+m)^2 < -n^2 - m^2 +1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a start,
let
$a_n = b_n-d$,
where $d$ will be determined soon.

Then
$a_{n+m}\leq a_{n}+a_{m}+C$
becomes
$b_{n+m}-d\leq b_{n}-d+b_{m}-d+C
$
or
$b_{n+m}\leq b_{n}+b_{m}-d+C
$.

Now,
let $d = C$,
and this becomes
$b_{n+m}\leq b_{n}+b_{m}
$.

This has now reduced the problem
to the standard subadditive problem.

You can now deduce that
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{b_n}{n}
$
exists,
so that
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{a_n}{n}
$
exists.

Comment: A rectification is required $a_n=b_n - d$ ...